# MariaDB Bitwise AND (&) operation

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

In my project, product Software architecture with 32 and 64 bits are stored in table as 21 and 22 respectively for various products.

I came across a SQL in which '*where*' clause mentioned as for **architecture 22**

```
'architecture & 2 = 2';
```

and **for architecture 21**

```
'architecture & 2 != 2';
```

I am not able to understand significance of above statements and what 2 = 2 doing in this SQL?

Comment: Please use parentheses to clarify the masking is done before the [in]equality test:  `(architecture & 2) = 2`.

Answer (score 2):

Generally `x & m = m` checks that all bits of mask `m` are set in the value of `x`.

Binary representation of 22 is 10110<sub>2</sub>, while binary representation of 21 is 10101<sub>2</sub>. When you apply `x & 2` mask to 22 you get 2 back, because two's bit, second bit from the right, is set in the value of 22. Hence `architecture & 2 = 2` would be `true`.

When you apply the same test to 21, you get back zero, because the second bit from the right is not set, so `architecture & 2 != 2` would be `true`.

Comment: You meant to say architecture & 2 != 2 would be FALSE?

Comment: @Shatru No, it would be true, because `0 != 2`

Answer (score 2):

architecture field should store a bitwise sum.

if the value of `architecture = 22` it means that `architecture = 2+4+16`

If the value of `architecture is 21` it means that `architecture = 1+4+16`

For the bitwise sum considers the range of values: 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64...

So, the expression

```
'architecture & 2 = 2';
```

is to check if the number 2 is stored in architecture field.

If `architecture is 21` the result is 0. So, is false.

If `architecture = 22` the result is 2. So, is true.

Answer (score 1):

That's used

> AND operators.

You could see [AND and OR logical](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLVMB_20.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/syn_transformation_expressions_and_or_logical_operators.htm)

`where 2=2` that is means true

You can turn to Binary like 1,2,4,8...

Comment: This link is not leading to mariadb or mysql documentation, though. In MariaDB it's a bitwise operator ([documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/bitwise_and/)).